# knockout js 'with' binding, hide if array is empty

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have a category drop down list which controls a sub category drop down list. I want to hide the sub categories drop down list if the sub category array is empty for the selected category.

Sample code below:

```
<script>

    self.categories = ko.observableArray([
            {"name": "top 1", "subcategories":[
                                              {"name": "sub 1"},
                                              {"name": "sub 2"}
                                              ]},
            {"name": "top 2", "subcategories":[]}
    ]);

    self.selected_category = ko.observable();
    self.selected_sub_category = ko.obserable();

</script>

<div>
    <select data-bind="options: categories, optionsText: "name", optionsCaption: "Select", value: selected_category"></select>
</div>  
<div data-bind="with:selected_category">
    <select data-bind="options: subcategories, optionsText: "name", optionsCaption: "Select", value: selected_sub_category"></select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to combine the `with` binding with the `if` (or the `visible`) binding where you can specify your condition:

```
<div data-bind="with: selected_category">
    <!-- ko if: subcategories.length > 0 -->
    <select data-bind="options: subcategories, optionsText: 'name', 
        optionsCaption: 'Select', value: $parent.selected_sub_category"></select>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Vvuxd/1/)

Note the usage of the `$parent` in the `value: $parent.selected_sub_category`, you need that to access "parent" object because the `with` creates a child context.

If you don't want to render the whole `div` when the sub collection is empty then you need to move the `with` and `if` outside your `div` because KO not allow to use multiple control-flow bindings on the same element.

So in that case your HTML would look like this:

```
<!-- ko with:selected_category -->
    <!-- ko if: subcategories.length > 0 -->
        <div class="mydiv">    
            <select data-bind="options: subcategories, optionsText: 'name', 
                    optionsCaption: 'Select', 
                    value: $parent.selected_sub_category">
            </select>    
        </div> 
    <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Vvuxd/2/)

Comment: Thanks nemesv. Is there a way to combine the with and if into the one data-bind attribute. The reason is that I would prefer it if the div was not rendered at all.

Comment: The `if` and `with` cannot be combined in on data-bind attribute. If you try it you will get the following error message: "Multiple bindings (with and if) are trying to control descendant bindings of the same element. You cannot use these bindings together on the same element." But you move them "outside" see my updated answer.